# How do I read an .npy file that contains a string?

Tags: rust, deserialization

I have a .npy file which contains tuples of one string (|S8) and 6 float values. I want to read the .npy in Rust as a vector of tuples.

I tried the `npyz` crate:

```rust
use npyz;

fn main() {
    read_depl_npy();
}

fn read_depl_npy() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let bytes = std::fs::read("test-data/test.npy")?;
    let npy = npyz::NpyFile::new(&bytes[..])?;
    println!("{:?}", npy.into_vec::<Depl>());
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(npyz::Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Depl {
    name: String,
    a: f64,
    b: f64,
    c: f64,
    d: f64,
    e: f64,
    f: f64,
}
```

I get this error:

```
the trait `Deserialize` is not implemented for `String`
```

Are there any other solutions or modification to this code that I could use?

I tried to open the .npy in Python and send it to Rust using `pyo3` by creating a Python module with Rust, but it's too inefficient. I wonder if [Calling Python in Rust code](https://pyo3.rs/latest/python_from_rust.html#calling-python-in-rust-code) would do any better.

## Upadte:

I'm not in control of the data in the .npy file. It is given to me as is. Here are the first 8 items in the file :

```
0000 = {void} (b'N1      ', 1.15423654e-05, nan, -8.63531175e-06, 0.00234345, -1.93959406e-05, nan)
0001 = {void} (b'N10     ', nan, 0.00014046, 9.3921465e-07, nan, -1.36987648e-05, -0.00021798)
0002 = {void} (b'N100    ', -2.95802408e-06, 5.02222077e-05, 5.02908617e-07, 0.00222162, nan, 0.00015162)
0003 = {void} (b'N1000   ', 1.11732508e-06, 0.00018788, nan, 0.00098555, -6.56358132e-06, -0.00021724)
0004 = {void} (b'N1001   ', -1.07967489e-06, 0.0001863, -3.29593367e-07, 0.00098565, nan, -0.00021703)
0005 = {void} (b'N1002   ', nan, 0.00018486, -4.39249772e-07, 0.00098573, -6.54476282e-06, -0.00021686)
0006 = {void} (b'N1003   ', -1.01067021e-06, 0.00018347, 8.16061298e-07, 0.00098576, -6.56198811e-06, -0.00021675)
0007 = {void} (b'N1004   ', 1.03888923e-18, 0.00016245, -2.65077262e-06, 0.0016541, -1.13024989e-05, -0.00022285)
0008 = {void} (b'N1005   ', 2.02031333e-18, 0.00016073, -1.84684389e-06, 0.00165515, -1.13003433e-05, -0.00022227)
```

And the data type:

```
[('name', 'S8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8'), ('e', '<f8'), ('f', '<f8')]
```

Comment: That crate does not support [deserializing Unicode strings](https://github.com/ExpHP/npyz/issues/2), so it seems. Are you in control of the data being read? Could the program depend on byte strings instead?

Comment: The question should be updated to provide instructions on how to *generate* the file so that an answerer can verify that their solution works.

Comment: I have updated the question. The data is already written on the disk and rewriting it is not an option, since it would take too long and we're talking about terabytes of data.